# Tour of Stack Exchange offices, other than NY HQ?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-hq

I really got the idea from [Is it possible to go on a tour of the Stack Exchange headquarters?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18187/is-it-possible-to-go-on-a-tour-of-the-stack-exchange-headquarters) I live closer to Denver, is there much of an office there? What about your London offices?

Can we have a sneak peak at the other offices as well?

Comment: If they say yes I'll get there with a nice home-made cake

Comment: I'll give you a tour of [my office](http://www.pikespeakbrewing.com/) if you buy me a beer...

Comment: Not sure about tagging this, apparently, [tag:stackexchange-tour] is supposed to mean something else.

Comment: Not sure either; I added a few likely tags.

Comment: Realistically speaking, what is interesting about a "backwater" office full of sales representatives  for whom SOCareers is just a thing they happen to be selling now?